# Как скомпилировать проект с несколькими файлами в Sublime Text 3

Tags: c++, mingw, sublime-text-3

Подскажите как я могу компилировать проекты в Sublime Text 3. Пытался настроить `"Build System"` файл, но безрезультатно.

Приведу пример, который у меня не получается скомпилировать.
В папке `D:\Test`, есть 4 файла.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    TestStruct test;
    test.show_info();

    return 0;
}
```

test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class TestStruct{
public:
    TestStruct(){
        cout << "counstructor" << endl;
    }

    void show_info();
};

#endif //TEST_H
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

void TestStruct::show_info(){
    cout << "message" << endl;
}
```

Четвертый файл это Makefile

```
all: main clean

main: main.o test.o
    g++ main.o test.o -o main

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

test.o: test.cpp test.h
    g++ -c test.cpp

clean:
    -del *.o $(BUILD_DIR)
```

Если убрать test.cpp и сделать реализацию в test.h файле, то программа будет компилироваться без проблем, но с реализацией test.cpp выдает примерно это:

> D:\Test>doskey make=mingw32-make.exe
> d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\7636~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cchKBpuW.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `TestStruct::show_info()'
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Где первая строчка выводится потому, что я мудрил с `make`, у меня он просто не определялся в консоли, но сейчас все работает. И если я перейду через командную строку в папку `D:\Test` и затем напишу `make`, то скомпилирует файл main.exe, а все *.o удалятся.

Забыл добавить, что я компилирую проект при помощи горячих клавиш благодаря плагину `Terminality`.

**Обновлено:**

CPP_RUN.sublime-build

```
{
"cmd": ["g++.exe","-std=c++14", "${file}", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&" , "${file_base_name}.exe<inputf.in>outputf.in"],
"shell":true,
"working_dir":"$file_path",
"selector":"source.cpp"
}
```

но, при сборке я так же получаю ошибку

> D:\Test>doskey make=mingw32-make.exe
> �� 㤠���� ���� 㪠����� 䠩�.
> [Finished in 1.0s with exit code 1]
> [cmd: ['g++.exe', '-std=c++14', 'D:\Test\main.cpp', '-o', 'main.exe', '&&', 'main.exe<inputf.in>outputf.in']]
> [dir: D:\Test]

Я думаю проще не найти ошибку в моих решениях, а подсказать как сделать все правильно с нуля.

**Обновлено:**

Подскажите кто знает, как реализовать то что я написал ниже.

При нажатии например на `CTRL+R` в консоли (которую мы не видим) вызывается команда make, которая соберет проект, а потом вызывалась команда открытия exe файла, который называется так же как файл в котором находится main. В моем случае main.exe. И все по факту это то, что нужно будет.

Comment: Я не разбираюсь в make, но, насколько мне известно, из `#pragma once` и `#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H ... #endif //TEST_H` стоит оставить что-то одно.

Comment: Зачем вам make файл? А какая команда выполняется при сборке?

Comment: @user7860670 вообще я думал, что как-то смогу запускать через st3 команду make, которая скомпилирует проект, вот для чего  make файл. А второй вопрос не очень понял. Если вам нужно содержимое `sublime-build`, то я обновил вопрос, а так я лично ничего не пишу,  а просто нажимаю сочетания клавиш `CTRL + R` чтобы скомпилировать или `CTRL + B` чтобы собрать.

Comment: @V-Mor да вы правы я почитал в чем различие между `#pragma once` и `#ifndef` и решил оставить `#ifndef`.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков cpprun похоже компилирует только один файл, а не запускает make. В этом и вся проблема

Comment: @KoVadim ну а вот как ее решить? дополнил вопрос идеей, но я не знаю, как консоль открыть в st3 и туда команды ввести

Comment: в sublime-build же первое поле cmd...

Comment: @user7860670 1) там надо две команды ввести и я не очень понимаю как это сделать. 2) Пожалуйста попробуй сделать это у себя, и если все получится напиши инструкция в виде ответа и если у меня все получится я отмечу его как правильный ответ.

Comment: почему две команды? ну первая - вызов make, а вторая?

Comment: @user7860670 а вторая запустить создавшийся exe файл. Т.к. иначе мне тогда уж проще будет через консоль самому две команды писать. Вот у меня идея появилась может какой-то батник создать, который запускать уже в st3?

Comment: добавьте запуск программы как еще одну цель (phony) в makefile тогда

Comment: @user7860670 в Makefile я записал в строчке `all: main clean run` и так же добавил две строчки `run: ./main` и при теперь exe запускается, но не появляется консоль, в диспетчере задаче висит пока я ее не завершу и все. Можете написать ПРИМЕР, что я должен написать. То есть не просто, что я должен сделать,  а в виде пример так я думаю процесс пойдет быстрей.

Comment: @user7860670 Я запустил через консоль и проблема оказалась в том, что в проекте есть команда cin а в st3 если я собираю сборку, то не могу ввести что либо. И последний шаг это нужно как-то запустить из st3 именно консоль с проектом.

Comment: @user7860670 в общем и целом, сделал я батник куда засунул запуск exe файла строго по названию main.exe. В `.sublime-build` засунул запуск make файла, но `make` у меня почему то не было видно, так что я просто написал `mingw32-make.exe` и так же запуск батника. Теперь после компилирования, запускается консоль как я и хотел в принципе, но если вы знаете способ избавится от батника и при этом работать будет так же, то буду благодарен если поделитесь идеей. Проблема в том, что любой открытый в st3 exe файл открывается в самом st3, а не в виде нового консольного окна.